# Android whitespace in imageview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

I am using a ViewPager to load images from server using Picasso. I see whitespace below the actual image. When I swipe the area with whitespace the image is swiped.
I have set **scaleType="fitXy"** to stretch to the ImageView's size.Below is the xml layout and code.
Please dont mark it as duplicate.I have googled it and the solutions did not help me.

@dimen/viewpager_img=150dp in w320dp-xhdpi

amblnce_display.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/amblnce_dsp_lyt"
    >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/viewpager_img"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

view_pager_lyt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/viewpager_img"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

ImagePagerAdapter.java:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context,String ctgry){
 if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("Ambulance")){
            count=AmbulanceDisplayData.getInstance().imagecount();
        }
layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
 @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.e("Count",Integer.toString(count));
        return count;
    }
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_lyt,container,false);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pgr_lyt);
         imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
   if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("Ambulance"))
        {
            count= ambulanceDisplayData.getInstance().imagecount();
            images =ambulanceDisplayData.getInstance().getArrayList();
            if(count!=0)
            {
                Log.e("Images", (String) images.get(position));
                Picasso.with(context).load("http://abcd.com/xyz/"+(String) images.get(position))
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
                        .fit().into(imageView);
            }
        }
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        if(view==object){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Set **[match_parent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT)** .

**Hard-Coded Value** causing problem here .

> MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
>   minus the parent's padding .

```
 <ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/image1"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  **android:adjustViewBounds="true"** like

```
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="@dimen/viewpager_img"
 android:id="@+id/image1"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 />
```

Comment: will try your answer

Comment: Ok, try it and if it worked except answer so the question will be closed

Comment: it didn't help me